# MyClass.inspect return incorrect class when I run whole test suite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, activemerchant, value-objects

## MyClass.inspect return incorrect class when I run whole test suite.

### Problem:

I have `User::CreditCard` and `ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard` classes in project. Last from activemerchant gem.
When I run single spec(`rspec spec/models/user/credit_card_spec.rb`) then it works correctly.
When I run whole suite(`rspec spec`) then spec fails with `undefined method...`, it doesn't matter. **The problem is that in this case, my `CreditCard` class is not mine!!!**
When I run single spec and do `puts User::CreditCard.inpsect`(or just `p User::CreditCard`, or in pry just `User::CreditCard`) then it returns `User::CreditCard` as expected.
**When I run whole suite and do `p User::CreditCard` inside spec then it returns `ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard`.**

---

### Background:

*If you don't want to read "background" then be sure that there are **NOTE** in the end*

I'm working with legacy code. So I don't fully know all parts of the image.

I want to create `Value Object` for credit card in my User. So I've create new tableless model(note the path and class name):

```
#app/models/user/credit_card.rb
class User::CreditCard
  include ActiveModel::Model

  delegate :card_number, :card_expiration, :card_type, to: :subscription

  def initialize(subscription)
    @subscription = subscription || Subscription.new
  end

  private

  attr_reader :subscription
end
```

Of course I have User model:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User
  ...
  has_one :subscription
  ...
  def credit_card
    @credit_card ||= User::CreditCard.new(subscription)
  end
end
```

My specs for user/credit_card:

```
#spec/models/user/credit_card_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
# require 'user/credit_card' # if I include this then it works correct

RSpec.describe User::CreditCard, type: :model do
  let(:subscription) { build :subscription }
  let(:credit_card) do
    p User::CreditCard # this result depends on whole/not whole suite run...
    # rspec spec => ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard
    # rspec spec/models/user => User::CreditCard
    User::CreditCard.new(subscription)
  end

  it 'should delegate alowed messages to user subscription' do
    %w[card_number card_expiration card_type].each do |attr|
      expect(credit_card.public_send(attr)).to eql subscription.public_send(attr)
    end
  end

  it 'disallow another methods' do
    expect { credit_card.unexisted_method }.to raise_error(NoMethodError)
  end
end
```

---

### NOTE:

in spec I can require 'user/credit_card' and then it will work. But why it does not work without it?
Can it be a problem in another places? For example in controllers or somewhere else?

Comment: @mudasobwa I'm not sure that this is simple to reproduce...

Comment: Anyway, I would guess that the problem roots are in `class User::CreditCard`. Rails does it’s voodoo autoloading, and since you have `class User` there is a collision between `User` being a class or module. Try to rename `User::CreditCard` to kinda `module UserDetails; class CredirCard`. It sounds weird, but there is no logic, neither prediction in how autoloading is handled.

Comment: @mudasobwa `…Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem` - I'm not sure that it can be reproduced by a little piece of code.
`…Complete – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem` - I'm not sure what should I add to `complete` my question...

Comment: Forget about MCVE, it sounds like here it is. The rule of thumb in Rails is: avoid namespacing collisions, specifically between classes and modules.

Comment: Great! It works:) But it is strange for me %)

Answer (score 1):

This is a glitch of rails autoloading + ruby constant resolution.

```
class C; end
CONST = 42
C::CONST
#⇒ (pry):3: warning: toplevel constant CONST referenced by C::CONST
#⇒ 42
```

Surprisingly enough, `CONST` **was resolved**. That is because of [Ruby constant resolution algorithm](https://valve.github.io/blog/2013/10/26/constant-resolution-in-ruby/).

One has two options to fix the problem: either to give a different name to the class `User::CreditCard` or to make sure it’s loaded. Otherwise Rails finds the constant `CreditCard` in `ActiveMerchant::Billing` namespace *and is happy with using it*.